# If I have a reference to a button how can I programatically fire the click event?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Through the infrastructure we've built, there is a command attached to a button, and through it's event handler, we get a reference to the button.

So, given that I have a reference to the button, how do I fire the click event?

Comment: Can you post the XAML for the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/TriggerEvent07162008140456PM/TriggerEvent.aspx) (relates to SLv2)? Or [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186553/sending-a-mouse-click-to-a-button-in-silverlight-2/3095409#3095409) (related to SLv3)? And finally, [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587412/how-to-fire-a-button-click-event-in-code-behind-in-user-control/3587683#3587683) (for SLv4)?

```
if (button is Button)
{
    ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer((Button)button);

    IInvokeProvider ip = (IInvokeProvider)peer;
    ip.Invoke();
}
```